# Network Socket - just the first message always completes

Tags: c#, sockets, object, networking

i've got the following problem in a client socket (sync) / server socket (async) environment.
If I send multiple messages from the client to the server, the first one finishs without any problems and will be received by the client without issues. When I send the 2nd message, just a few bytes go through. It doesn't seem to be a client problem, because it looks the client sends the whole message all the time. The crazy thing is, if I completely stop the project on the client and start again the first message completes again, also if the server component runs through all the time.

What I want to do...
Basically, I want to transfer different objects, most xml structured through the network and receive it on the client. Therefore, I do the Serialization/Deserialization.
The basics of the following code are extended msdn examples.

//CLIENT:

```
class ProgramClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rootNode = "config";

        StreamReader configStream = new StreamReader(config);

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(configStream);

        SynchronousSocketClient socket = new SynchronousSocketClient("192.168.0.1", 40001, "c:\\log", xml);
        socket.StartClient();
        socket.Dispose();
        socket = new SynchronousSocketClient("192.168.0.1", 40001, "c:\\log", xml);
        socket.StartClient();
        socket.Dispose();
    }
}


class SynchronousSocketClient : IDisposable
{
    private string ip;
    private int port;
    private object data;
    public StreamWriter log;

    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    public SynchronousSocketClient(string ip, int port, string logfile, object data)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.data = data;
        openLog(logfile);
    }

    public void openLog(string logfile)
    {
        log = new StreamWriter(logfile, true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        log.Close();
        if (this.Disposed != null)
            this.Disposed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Convert an object to a byte array
    private byte[] Serialize(object obj)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(stream, obj);
        byte[] b = null;
        b = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(b, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        stream.Close();
        return b;
    }

    public void StartClient()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.
    try {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,port);

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+": Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            byte[] msg = Serialize(data);

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": {0}",
                Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

            // Release the socket.
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
            log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+": "+e.ToString());
    }

    }
}
```

//SERVER:

```
class ProgramServer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkSocket socket = new NetworkSocket(nwsocketport);
        socket.Start();
    }
}



public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of send buffer.
    public const int sBufferSize = 1024;
    // send buffer.
    public byte[] sBuffer = new byte[sBufferSize];
    // Received data object;
    public object data = null;
    // bytes read so far
    public int bytesRead;
    //receive buffer
    public byte[] rBuffer;
}

public class NetworkSocket
{
    private int port;
    Socket listener;

    IPEndPoint localEndPoint;


    public NetworkSocket(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void Start() {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        //set socket timeouts
        listener.SendTimeout = 5000;
        listener.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(1);
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        //allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        state.rBuffer = new Byte[listener.ReceiveBufferSize];

        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.rBuffer, 0, state.rBuffer.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        try
        {
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        //handler.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        state.bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        Send(handler, "paket successfully tranferred");
        state.data = Deserialize(state.rBuffer);

        bool xmlDoc = true;

        try
        {
            XDocument.Parse(state.data.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            xmlDoc = false;
        }

        if (xmlDoc)
            XMLHandler.update(state.data.ToString());


    }

    private void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    // Convert a byte array to an Object
    private object Deserialize(byte[] b)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(b);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        object obj = bf.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return obj;
    }

    // convert object to byte array
    private byte[] Serialize(object obj)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(stream, obj);
        byte[] b = null;
        b = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(b, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        stream.Close();
        return b;
    }

}
```

Could anybody please help me with my problem? I am not experienced in Socket Programming...

Comment: Sorry... above I wanted to say:What I want to do... Basically, I want to transfer different objects, most xml structured through the network and receive it on the server!

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to read all of that code? Any chance you could narrow down that problem to a reasonable amount of code?

Comment: Sorry....
The problem happens on the server side, if I send the 2nd object from the client to the server .
When the following line will be called on the server:
   state.bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
in bytesRead, just a few bytes are inside.

example:

the object I send has 13679 bytes. On the client, it looks like all the time, all of these 13679 bytes are send properly to the server.
On the server side, the first time, bytesRead is 13679. The second time, its just: 2982.

Comment: If I completely stop the client project and start it 5 times (just send one object and stop/start it again), the whole time 13679 bytes will be received by the server.


Does that explain it a little bit better?

Thanks and Regards,
Maik

Comment: No, it still doesn't explain why you expect me to read all of that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ReadCallback` you need to start another `BeginReceive`, just like how you call `BeginAccept` in the `AcceptCallback` method.

A more serious issue with your code is that you expect to receive one entire message per `ReadCallback`. In reality, you could receive half a message, one byte, or three messages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! It seems to be working fine now. I added a recursive call of BeginReceive in ReadCallback. Additionally, I also work through the buffer and save it into a new object. If one transfer cannot be completed within one Receive, the additional data will be append to the new object. It works fine so far. Thanks a lot for your help! :)